# three.js line:17299:4 warning X4121 - how can this be prevented to "improve performance"?

Tags: three.js, compiler-warnings, fragment-shader

I'm getting this warning 
in Firefox console (F12):

[image]

and in Chrome too:

[image]

What should I do to prevent this warning and "improve performance"?

**EDIT**: the following three.js examples raise the same warning:

```
animation / cloth
postprocessing / outline 
postprocessing / sao 
postprocessing / ssao
physics / cloth 
physics / convex / break 
physics / rope
```

I have checked only a few -probably there are more.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share your code as a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/)? Besides, you are using Windows, right?

Comment: Sorry, I can't do that. Yes, I 'm using Windows 7.

Comment: Do you see the warning with the official examples of `three.js`, too? https://threejs.org/examples/

Comment: There's an answer here and a bit more background on what could be happening:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33175398/can-i-avoid-texture-gradient-calculations-in-webgl

Comment: @Mugen87   Good question,  yes!  The very first three.js example "animation / cloth" raises the same warning, while the second one raises multiple warnings of the type: "warning X3571: pow(f, e) will not work for negative f, use abs(f) or conditionally handle negative values if you expect them".
So there is an example that can be studied -although there might be multiple causes for the same warning.

Comment: @pailhead   -I've seen that, but there is a much more informative one but needs ...translation to webgl:
https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/533200-dx10-hlsl-gradient-based-operation-error/

Comment: @Mugen87 Also I tried the postprocessing examples since I'm doing some custom postprocessing and found that the following three.js examples raise the same warnings:  postprocessing / outline, postprocessing / sao, postprocessing / ssao. Also: physics / cloth,  physics / convex / break, physics / rope. Probably there are more. 
My VGA card is Geforce GTX 560 Ti  -if that helps.